# “ContentView.swift” is currently locked for editing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to open and edit the existing SwiftUI **ContentView.swift** project.
But I'm getting below error

> **ContentView.swift” is locked for editing and you may not be able to
>   save your changes. Do you want to unlock it?**
>   “ContentView.swift” is currently locked for editing.
>   [image]

I'm trying to Unlock but it's not working.

> **The file “ContentView.swift” could not be unlocked**
>   
>  Unlocking failed for an unknown reason.
>   [image]

Comment: Did you try to restart Xcode?

Comment: Make sure the following checked _Xcode > Preferences > General > Locked Files: Automatically unlock files_. If it does... check permissions in file system using Terminal.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I've already checked it's not working